# How to download all the comments from a news article using Python?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have to admit that I don't know much html. I am trying to extract all the comments from an article in the online news using python. I tried using python BeautifulSoup, but it seems comments are not in the html source-code, but present in the inspect-element. For instance you can check here. http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-5100519/Elon-Musk-says-Tesla-Roadster-special-option.html#comments

My code is here and I am struck.

```
        import urllib.request as urllib2
        from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
        url = "http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-5100519/Elon-Musk-says-Tesla-Roadster-special-option.html#comments"
        page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
```

I want to do this

```
    name_box = soup.find('p', attrs={'class': 'comment-body comment-text'})
```

but this info is not there in the source-code.

Any suggestion, how to move forward?

Answer (score 2):

I have not attempted things like this, but my guess is if you want to get it directly from "page source" you'll need something like selenium to actually navigate the page since the page is dynamic.

Alternatively if you're only interested in comments you may use the dailymail.co.uk's api to acquire comments.

Note the items in the querystring "max=1000" "&order" etc.  You may also need to use the variable "offset" along side max to find all the comments if the API has a limit on the maximum "max" value.

I do not know where the API is defined, you can view it by view the network requests that your browser makes while you search the webpage.

You can get comment data from http://www.dailymail.co.uk/reader-comments/p/asset/readcomments/5100519?max=1000&order=desc&rcCache=shout for that page in JSON format.  It appears that every article has something like "5101863" in its url, you can use swap those numbers for each new story that you want comments about.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you FredMan. I did not know about this API. It seems we need to give only the article id and we can the comments from the article. This was the solution I was looking for.